# importing modules with relative paths - best way to handle?

Tags: python, import, relative-path

Here's the basic file structure

```
./main_func.ipynb
./data/
     ./some_code.py
./util/
     ./some_func.py
```

In some_code.py, I use a relative import to import some_func along the lines of:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'../util')
import some_func
```

Which works fine within some_code.py, but if I import some_code.py into main_func.ipynb, the relative path stuff in some_code.py gets messed up as the working directory is now at './' instead of './data/'.

**The question I have is what is the cleaner way of doing this?** I can't move the scripts as other people rely on their current location. Currently I include the path to util as an input to some_func.py and then do the import, but that feels like a bad workaround.

My coding knowledge is largely self-taught as need be, so I may be missing some super basic code organization thing like some type of pathing file or something of that sort.

I've seen plenty of posts about relative path imports, but none about importing things with relative path imports. Sorry if I've missed one though, but I've spent an hour or so looking for one to no avail.